# DNS Forwarding (Redirect) with Masking

Tags: iis, dns, bind

Any ideas on how to accomplish this or it is not possible.

1.) Own a domain, mycompany.com

2.) mycompany.com is registered at GoDaddy

3.) mycompany.com nameservers are pointed to "My Company's" on-premise infrastructure.  The nameservers must remain this way.  The on-premise solution uses Bind for DNS services.

4.) mycompany.com has a CNAME, hosting.mycompany.com

5.) the zone record at the on-premise DNS points hosting.mycompany.com to an IIS7 VPS at GoDaddy.  Let's call this box VPS7.

6.) VPS7 has a dummy IIS ASP.NET site with basically just a web.config with code in it (destination redacted):

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="**redacted**" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>`

The above configuration allows a user to surf to hosting.mycompany.com and gets redirected to a GoDaddy reseller site. BUT (obviously) the user's browser's address bar then shows the GoDaddy (secureserver.net) domain instead of hosting.mycompany.com.

Is there a way to retain the hosting.mycompany.com in the address bar instead of secureserver.net without too much trouble?

What I've tried / thought about already:

a.) can we simply use the GoDaddy nameservers (instead of the on-premise mycompany nameserver), and then use GoDaddy's "Forward w/ Masking" feature?  ...no, the nameservers have to remain as they are.

b.) could I just remove the web.config redirect, create a single page, and then just iframe the entire reseller site?  ...haven't tried this, but it seems like just a horrible solution.

Thoughts/Ideas?
TIA!
~Ted

Comment: https://uk.godaddy.com/help/use-a-custom-domain-for-my-storefront-5040

Comment: Oh wow! Duh! I never saw that setting in their control panel. THANK YOU!!